# How to automatically connect a logged in User to submit a document

Tags: python, django, view, model, user-input

Please I am new to coding, I am currently working on an app where there are various users trying to submit a document, I want them to be able to view only the documents they upload, while the admin can view all the users' documents. I was able to accomplish this but in this case the user field is a foreign key at the backend, and it's showing a drop down on the front end, I want each user to be automatically assigned to theirs, please how do I accomplish this.

This is the `model.py`

```
class Report(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, null=True, blank=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    name = models.ForeignKey(Staff, null=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
    reportname = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True)
    date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, null=True)
    report=models.FileField(upload_to='pdf/')
    def __str__(self):
        return self.reportname
```

`the view.py`

```
@login_required(login_url='loginpage')
def report (request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = ReportForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            
            form.user = request.user
            form.save()

            # Redirect to the document list after POST
            messages.info(request,'Submitted Sucessfully')
            return redirect('submitted_report')
        
    else:
            form = ReportForm() # A empty, unbound form

    return render(request,'report.html',{
      'form':form,'repor':report
      }
    )


@login_required(login_url='loginpage')
def submitted_report(request):
    report = Report.objects.filter(user=request.user)
    return render(request,'submitted_report.html',{
        'report': report
        })
```

Comment: In your ModelForm, add an `exclude = ['user']` under the `class Meta`. This should hide the user field in your html.

Comment: Please, I’ve tried that before, that’s not the issue, the issue is that the form is not submitting on the user page, If I exclude the user in the model.py I’ll the user won’tbe automatically associated with the logged in user

Comment: Currently the under field is showing a drop down, but I want it to be automatically associated with the user logged it, so that the user can submit a form, and he can view just his form on his page

Comment: use what I showed above and set the user the way you did earlier `form.user = request.user`